# Transferring data from different tables into dimension table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, dimension, insert-into

I am trying to fill my product dimension with data from AdventureWorks database using the following query

```
SELECT product.Class,
    product.Color,
    product.DaysToManufacture,
    product.DiscontinuedDate,
    product.ProductLine,
    product.FinishedGoodsFlag,
    product.ListPrice,
    product.MakeFlag,
    product.Name AS productName,
    productDescription.[Description],
    product.ProductNumber,
    product.ReorderPoint,
    product.SafetyStockLevel,
    product.SellEndDate,
    product.SellStartDate,
    product.Size,
    product.StandardCost,
    product.Style,
    product.[Weight],
    model.Name AS model,
    product.WeightUnitMeasureCode,
    product.SizeUnitMeasureCode,
    subcategory.Name AS subcategoryName,
    category.Name AS categoryName,
    photo.LargePhoto,
    photo.LargePhotoFileName,
    photo.ThumbNailPhoto,
    photo.ThumbnailPhotoFileName
    FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.Product product
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductModel model 
    ON (product.ProductModelID = model.ProductModelID)
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductSubcategory subcategory
    ON (subcategory.ProductSubcategoryID = product.ProductSubcategoryID)
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductCategory category
    ON (category.ProductCategoryID = subcategory.ProductCategoryID)
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductProductPhoto productphoto
    ON (productphoto.ProductID = product.ProductID)
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductPhoto photo
    ON (productphoto.ProductPhotoID = photo.ProductPhotoID)
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductModelProductDescriptionCulture productModelDescription
    ON (productModelDescription.ProductModelID = model.ProductModelID)
    INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductDescription productDescription
    ON (productModelDescription.ProductDescriptionID = productDescription.ProductDescriptionID)
    WHERE productModelDescription.CultureID = 'en';
```

However there are 504 product records in Product tables, but this query yields only 294 records. After tracing the query for a while, I figured out that the joins to get product description is the reason for the deducted number of product records.
My question is how to get All product records (504) while getting product description information as well, if not found put NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can use FULL OUTER JOIN with ProductDescription table.

```
.....   
..... 
INNER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductModelProductDescriptionCulture productModelDescription 
            ON (productModelDescription.ProductModelID = model.ProductModelID)
        FULL OUTER JOIN AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.ProductDescription productDescription
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

By using LEFT JOIN you will get all products. INNER JOIN will remove the once rows that do not match in your ON statement.

Edit: This image shows you the results from the different types of joins: [image: Sql joins]

You can see there that by using INNER JOIN you only get the rows where both tables overlap, while using LEFT JOIN you will always return the full set of the first table.